# Generate Templates from Json variables

Tags: ruby, json, loops, hash, erb

I want to generate some zabbix templates for some local microservices (variables stored in a json file), please see the code below:

```
def self.haproxyTemplates
  file = File.read('./services.json')
  data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

  service = data_hash.keys
  service.each do |microservice|
  puts "Microservice: #{microservice}"
  httpport = data_hash["#{microservice}"]['httpport']
  puts "httpPort: #{httpport}"
  end

  open("./haproxy.xml", 'w+') { |f| f.chmod(0755)
  template=IO.read('./haproxyhealth.xml.erb')
  x = ERB.new(template).result(binding)
  f << "#{x}\n"
  }
end
```

And this is my services.json file:

```
{
 "microservice1":{
  ....... ,
  "httpport": "27200"
   },
   "microservice2":{
   ......,
   "httpport": "25201"
   }
}
```

Basically in this method when I'm doing the loop for each microservice it run successfully until it ends the loop. When it creates the haproxy.xml it shows
" undefined local variable or method `httpport' for main:Object (NameError)"
I tried to put httpport variable outside the loop and it's shows the same error.

Please also see a part of the erb file(if I replace the <%= httpport %> with 25201, the file is generated corectly):

```
 <items><% service.each do |microservice| %>
            <item>
                <name>haproxy <%= microservice %> - <%= httpport %></name>
 ......
 </item><% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example, if you paste this into a ".rb" file, then you can run it.

Problem with your version: `binding` does not contain `httport` (and even if it would contain it, it would be the same for all microservices because it does not get re-assigned.): solution: access the the JSON (ruby hash) data in the template and then loop from there.

```
require 'erb'

# data = parse JSON from file, inline here as example

data = {
  'microservice1' => {
    'httpport' => '27200'
  },
  'microservice2' => {
    'httpport' => '27201'
  }
}

open("haproxy.xml", 'w+') do |file|
  template = ERB.new(DATA.read)
  file << template.result(binding)
  file << "\n"
end


__END__
<items>
  <% data.each do |name, info| %>
    <item>
      <name>haproxy <%= name %> - <%= info['httpport'] %></name>
    </item>
  <% end %>
</items>
```

Comment: Thanks, is working but with <items> ... </items> in the .erb file